# Passing Argument via Command Line php

Tags: php, command-line, scraper

So I have this script that I'm trying to pass the argument via command line.
But, can't get it to work.  Here's the code for the script:

```
#!/usr/bin/php 

<?php
$argv[1] = $scraper;
require_once('Scraper.php');
$scraper = new JonH_Scraper();

if (empty($argv[1])) {
    echo 'whats the URL?';
    }

$scraper->scrape($url);
var_dump($scraper);
```

Comment: What do you mean by it's not working? Is there an error, or does it just print out 'Whats the URL'?

Comment: You should either `exit` or `die` in the case where your command line argument is not present. Using the code you entered here, `$scraper->scrape()` gets called even when the argument is empty.

Comment: What errors do you get, and check your include path, too. Add a `var_dump($argv);` and set the `-n` flag on your hashbang, or... there's sooooo many things that could be causing funny things to happen... more info needed

Comment: Top Google result: http://www.electrictoolbox.com/command-line-arguments-php-cli/

Answer (score 4):

the mistake is here

```
$argv[1] = $scraper;
```

it should be

```
$scraper = $argv[1];
```

regards

Answer (score 4):

I believe the problem is with this line:

```
$argv[1] = $scraper;
```

You assign `$scraper` to `$argv[1]` but `$scraper` is undefined so the assignment becomes null.  Later on you check if `$argv[1]` is empty, which it will be since its `NULL`.

Perhaps it should be reversed?

```
$scraper = (isset($argv[1])) ? $argv[1] : null;

if (empty($scraper)) die('No url provided');
```

EDIT:  You may want to use a different variable name since you go ahead and create a new `Scraper` object and assign it to that same variable.

Answer (score 1):

Should be something like this:

```
php script.php <URL>


#!/usr/bin/php 
<?php
require_once('Scraper.php'); 
$url = $argv[1];
if(empty($url)){
 die('URL is EMPTY');
}
$scraper = new Scraper();
$results = $scraper->scrape($url);
var_dump($results);
```

Comment: Just FYI, $argv[0] is the name of the php script itself, argv[1] is the first argument passed on the command line.

Comment: Thanks for seeing that @drew010

Comment: I'm still not getting any results

Comment: `#!/usr/bin/php 
<?php
$scraper = $argv[1];
require_once('Scraper.php');
$scraper = new JonH_Scraper();

$scraper = (isset($argv[1]));

if (empty($argv[1])) {
    die('No url provided');
    }


$scraper->scrape($url);
var_dump($scraper);`

Comment: Why are you assigning the $scaper variable from the passed in argument? Shouldn't you be assigning the $url variable from the argument. Let me extend my code above a bit to fill in the blanks.

Comment: Hey Roger,  I just tried it with your recommendation, and its still not producing anything.

Comment: I am not sure what the scraper class does, so to take that out of the equation. Can you try running something like this? <?php $url = $argv[1]; echo $url; ?>